# Different behaviour between different TeX engines

Tags: plain-tex, engine

Consider this simple piece of code, which is part of a format file I found.

```
\catcode`\@=11

\ch@ck0\insc@unt\count

\bye
```

Why does it work fine with both `tex` and `pdftex` but issues an error message for `xetex` and `luatex`?

Comment: @Marijin  Thank you, but I think this has nothing to do with fonts.  \ch@ck and \insc@unt are two control sequences defined in the plain format:  maybe xetex and luatex load a format which is slightly different from Knuth's plain.

Comment: @Marijn No problem, thank you anyways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the error in pdftex as well, you presumably have an older release.

If you change it to

```
\catcode`\@=11

\show\ch@ck



\bye
```

then with tex you get

```
> \ch@ck=macro:
#1#2#3->\ifnum \count 1#1<#2\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}\fi .
l.3 \show\ch@ck

?
```

but with formats that have included the etex.src macros to allow allocation above 255 you get

```
> \ch@ck=macro:
#1#2#3#4->\ifnum \count 1#1 < #2#4\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}\fi .
l.3 \show\ch@ck

?
```

with a 4 argument form which in your code picks up the `\par` from the blank line and errors.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the plain macros loaded are different, as I guessed.  Thank you!